# MSFTCompression.Core.Cab throws exception "part of a directory not found"

Tags: c#, .net-core, wix

When using `MSFTCompression.Core.Cab (Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab)` I always get the message:

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:" Could not find a part of the path 'C: \ Users \ myUser \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \'. "`

I can see what this message means, but I can't figure out why it is being thrown.

The path is definitely there and i have fullrights.

Here my code as an example:

```
CabInfo cab = new CabInfo ("Test.cab");
cab.Pack (myFolderWithFiles, false, CompressionLevel.Max, null);
```

the error is thrown in the `cab.Pack` line.
Internally, the routine apparently uses the user's local \ temp and does not seem to find it.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

I am using .NET Core 3.1

I've since found out that it actually appears to be a bug. Because if I use the same NuGet from DotNet Standard ( MSFTCompression.Cab `not core`), everything goes fine.

Only in this case I have the warning that the package was released for .NET and not for Core.

Anyone see anything that suggests it is not a bug?

Comment: Please update to newer version (1.0.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seems to have a different opinion than me, I accept my own answer, namely that the package with Core in the name does not work or contains a bug.

Incidentally, the Nuget `MSFTCompression.Cab` works perfectly with .NetCore

`(only tested with Windows, As expected, it will not work with others)`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing with MSFTCompression.Core.Cab.
I asked the creator, he wants to fix that. So it's a bug